# R plotly subplot share X axis and Share Y axis

Tags: r, plotly, subplot, ggplotly

I am trying to create group bars for a scatter plot on the x-axis and y-axis, eventually, I will embed this in R markdown and hence need the interactivity too.
I have x-axis bar and y-axis bar and want the axis of these bar plots to share the axis on my main scatter plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)


x <-  sample(1:1000, 10, replace=FALSE)
y <-  sample(1001:2000, 10, replace=FALSE)

#main df
df <- data.frame(pos1 = c(x[1:5], y[1:5]), pos2 =c(x[6:10], y[6:10]), Sample = c(rep("Sample1", 5), rep("Sample2", 5)))

#axis df
df2 <- data.frame(Sample = c("Sample1", "sample2"), pos1 = c(1,1001), pos2 = c(1000,2000))
df2$x_median <- (df2$pos1 + df2$pos2)/2


#Main plot
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=pos1, y=pos2, fill = Sample)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())

# X-axis bar
ann_x <- ggplot(data = df2) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = pos1,
                xmax = pos2,
                ymin = 0,
                ymax = 0.4,
                fill = as.factor(Sample)),
            color = "black",
            size = 0.3,
            alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_text(aes(x = x_median, y = .2, label = Sample), vjust = .8, fontface = "bold", color = "black") +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")

#y-axis bar
ann_y <- ggplot(data = df2) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 0,
                xmax = .4,
                ymin = pos1,
                ymax = pos2,
                fill = as.factor(Sample)),
            color = "black",
            size = 0.3,
            alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_text(aes(x = .2, y = x_median, label = Sample), vjust = .8, fontface = "bold", color = "black", angle = 90) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")

Noax <- list(
  title = "",
  zeroline = FALSE,
  showline = FALSE,
  showticklabels = FALSE,
  showgrid = FALSE,
  showlegend = F 
)


fig_main <- ggplotly(p)
fig_x <- ggplotly(ann_x) %>%
  layout(xaxis = Noax,
         yaxis = Noax)
fig_y <- ggplotly(ann_y) %>%
  layout(xaxis = Noax,
         yaxis = Noax)

subplot(fig_x, fig_main,  shareX = TRUE, nrows = 2,  heights =  c(0.1, 0.90), which_layout = 1)
subplot(fig_main,fig_y , widths = c(0.9, 0.1), shareY = TRUE)
```

I am able to share axis for either X or Y, but not both.

[image: Shared X-axis]

[image: Shared Y-axis]

I need something like this:

[image]

Appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way may be to build these shapes in Plotly and attach them to `fig_main`.

Initially, I added your block labels outside of the plot, but this becomes an issue when you resize the plot (it will cause the text to shift). By adding the shapes to the plot space, resizing will not move the text.

I created vectors to hold the values for the shapes (where the color blocks will come from) and the annotations (where the text in the color blocks will come from). I also changed the x and y axis limits so that these blocks would go into the plot space.

The data in these vectors will create the blocks in the following order: along the right side (aligned with the y-axis), bottom, then top, then along the top (aligned with the x-axis), left side, then right.

First, just with the main plot and extra plot space

```
fig_m2 <- ggplotly(p)
fig_m2 %>% layout(showlegend = F, xaxis = list(range = c(0, 2000)),
                  yaxis = list(range = c(0, 2000)))
```

Next, building the blocks of colors—the shapes. In Plotly `x0` is equivalent to `xmin` in `ggplot`. `x1` is `xmax`.

```
xs = c(1750, 2000, 1750, 2000, 0, 1000, 1001, 2000) # vals for x-axis
ys = c(0, 1000, 1001, 1750, 1750, 2000, 1750, 2000) # vals for x-axis

cols <- ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]]$fill %>% unique() # get colors from ggplot
# [1] "#F8766D" "#00BFC4"     # red-ish and blue-ish

cols = rep(cols, each = 2) %>% rep(times = 2)       # color vector for shapes

# build shapes
shp <- invisible(lapply(seq(1, 7, by = 2), # count by 2s
                        function(i) { 
                          list(type = "rect", opacity = .2,
                               x0 = xs[i], x1 = xs[i + 1],
                               y0 = ys[i], y1 = ys[i + 1],
                               xref = "x", yref = "y",
                               fillcolor = cols[i],
                               line = list(width = 0)) # don't outline*
                        }))
```

To add this to the plot, you have to pull any shapes already in the plot first. (Since you started with `ggplotly`, there is at least one shape in the object.)

```
shp2 <- fig_m2$x$layout$shapes              # collect shapes in plot
fig_m2$x$layout$shapes <- append(shp2, shp) # consolidate & add shapes to plot
```

There are color blocks but no labels yet. If you wanted to see where we're at, this is what we've got so far:

```
fig_m2 %>% layout(showlegend = F, xaxis = list(range = c(0, 2000)),
                  yaxis = list(range = c(0, 2000)))
```

[image]

For the text, there is no min and max, just x or y.

```
# build labels (annotations) inside the shapes
tx = rep(df2$Sample, 2)
xa = c(1875, 1875, 500, 1500)
ya = c(xa[3:4], xa[1:2])
ta = c(90, 90, 0, 0)
annot <- invisible(lapply(1:4,
                          function(k) {
                            list(showarrow = F, text = tx[k],
                                 x = xa[k], y = ya[k],
                                 xref = "x", yref = "y",
                                 align = "middle", valign = "middle",
                                 textangle = ta[k])
                          }))

fig_m2 %>% layout(showlegend = F, xaxis = list(range = c(0, 2000)),
                  yaxis = list(range = c(0, 2000)),
                  annotations = annot)
```

This is what you've got, now.

[image]